# 3D Image in Three.js

Tags: three.js

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_large_mesh
http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_lights_pointlights

Please see above link. Can anyone please tell how to create and render moving person or statue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `three.js` you can easily `create and render moving person or statue`

on the first link the statue is no moved , it is done using `camera animation`(changing the position of camera accoring to the movement of mouse in the canvas)

for a moving person ,you should go for `morph animation`

[morph animation three.js](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_morph.html)

Comment: @Rahul Labde  You can create the 3d models using software such as Maya,blender etc